# Listing Team Drive Files: Error 403 insufficientPermissions

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm trying to access the files of my Team Drive, but I got a 403 error, while I can access to my files of my normal Google Drive.

Is it necessary to add a specific permission on the OAuth key ?

```
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT =         GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    Drive service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();


    String pageToken = null;
    do {
      TeamDriveList result = service.teamdrives().list()
          .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
          .setUseDomainAdminAccess(true)
          .setPageToken(pageToken)
          .execute();
      for (TeamDrive file : result.getTeamDrives()) {
        System.out.printf("Found file: %s (%s)\n",
            file.getName(), file.getId());
      }
      pageToken = result.getNextPageToken();
    } while (pageToken != null);
```

And the response :

```
    Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
    {
      "code" : 403,
      "errors" : [ {
        "domain" : "global",
        "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
        "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
      } ],
      "message" : "Insufficient Permission"
    }
```

Comment: which oAuth2 scopes are you requesting??

Comment: I am getting the same issue when I try to create a TeamDrive, with auth/drive scope, using the super admin of my organization.